# Append SubResult List To Result List

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, recursion, combinations

I'm trying to solve Leetcode [Combinations Sum](https://leetcode.com/problems/combination-sum/) Problem and i've did using recursion method. Pasting my approach here

```
def combinationSum(candidates,target):
    N = len(candidates)
    FinRes = []
    SubRes = []
    def Helper(Ind,candidates,target,FinRes,SubRes):
        if(Ind == len(candidates)):
            if(target == 0):
                FinRes.append(SubRes.copy()) # Adding SubRes To FinRes
            return
        if(candidates[Ind] <= target):
            SubRes.append(candidates[Ind])
            Helper(Ind,candidates,target-candidates[Ind],FinRes,SubRes)
            SubRes.pop()
        Helper(Ind+1,candidates,target,FinRes,SubRes)
        
    Helper(0,candidates,target,FinRes,SubRes)
    return FinRes

candidates = [2,3,6,7]                                                                                              
target = 7
print(combinationSum(candidates,target))
```

In my recursion function `Helper` in base case when `target==0` I'm appending my `SubRes` to `FinRes`. I've tried `FinRes.append(SubRes)` but its not appending to `FinRes` (It's actually appending and removing later) later when i did `SubRes.copy()` its working fine. So how can i add `SubRes` with just `append`.

Comment: No @DanielHao I'm learning recursion. So wanted to do with this.

Comment: OK. Try the next approach in post.

Answer (score 0):

What about this version, you could try it.

```
def combinationSum(self, candidates, target):
    candidates.sort()    # sort first to make later comparison easier 
    
    def helper(candidates, target):
        result = []      # each `sublist` is an answer to the reduced problem
        if candidates:
            for i, x in enumerate(candidates):
                if x < target:
                   sublist = helper(candidates[i:], target -x) # reduce the problem...
                   #print(sublist)
                   for sub in sublist:
                       sub.append(x)
                       result.append(sub)
                elif target == x:
                    result.append([x])
                # the subsequent x's will be larger than the target, so skip 
                else:
                    break
         return result
        
     result = helper(candidates, target)
     return result
```